# SNMP Messages for failed logon with a PostgreSQL Log

Tags: postgresql, logging, snmp

Currently my application runs and inserts events into a protected PostgreSQL DB. That's cool and it allows for audit of user login and such.

What I would like to do is be able to take failed login events after they reach a certain threshold and report those via SNMP Message to another service (like a snmp server). I just can't seem to wrap my head around how.

I thought of maybe using POST to a failed page and inside of that PHP script a system to post to PostgreSQL and query events by user by time but it seems brutal. Maybe Python? I have options but I can't think of a good implementation. Help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following approach:

1. on insert trigger on table where login attempts were logged to check number of attempts and then
2. when login attempts threshold achieved send NOTIFY notification
3. finally external service LISTEN for notification and
4. upon it receives one send SNMP message broadcast

For more info see: 
[NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-notify.html) and [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-listen.html)